# Prevent user to disable the app from app info - Android

Tags: android

I am building an app for which I want to prevent user from disabling or uninstall of the app from app info. The app will be distributed manually (it will not go on play store) and will be installed on the organisational devices only.

I am able to prevent uninstall of the app by following method:

- root the device
- install the app in /system/priv-app folder
- unroot the device

After successful execution of the above step, uninstall button is not visible but disable button is there. Is there a similar method for preventing the "disable" option as well?

Thanks

Comment: This can cause HUGE security concerns. Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: This app is built for an organisation and the app will be only installed on the devices owned by that particular organisation and will not go to the users device. The app is built for monitoring the device use and collect some data for analysis.

Comment: Consider doing something like this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13375/prevent-uninstall-of-apps

Comment: Ask the organization to hand out their own devices with their compliation of the OS with the app. Either way you are spying on users and probably voilating their privacy in some ways.

Comment: Just to expand on what @UmerFarooq stated. If you can force a user to not uninstall or even disable a application, once it is running, then the user holds no more control over the device (security wise, this is very bad.... but it is exactly what manufacturers do. You cant even uninstall their `crapware`).

Comment: Yes I understand the security concerns but here the device owner is the organisation itself. This device will be handed to number of testers who will go in the field to collect the data. The requested options are to just ensure that no one should uninstall the app or disable it even accidentally. After testing the tester will return the device back to the organisation.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically Use the [DeviceAdmin](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) and implement the DeviceAdminReceiver registering for ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED. In your onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) method use package manager to re-enable the app and send an appropriate message.

I think you should probably look more closely at device admin and see if you can implement whatever it is your app does within that context and without requiring that you root the phones.  Rooting the phones and installing some kind of private app sounds like a total nightmare in terms of the additional work it will require you to do and it also possibly introduces a huge security hole into your users phones.

Answer (score 0):

You did not write what your application do. I think instead of taking away possibility to disable the application, you should ASK them to not uninstall or disable it. I do not think you can prevent them to disable your application without more system modifications.

Whatever it does, it may report to your server and missing report would mean they do not cooperate (or cannot reach your network). If you gave them devices, you should ask them to use them according to your rules. It can for example log periodically its presence. It those log (device local or remote) are missing, user did not obey rules. It is not required to know what exactly they were doing. But you know they did not obey rules that time.

I think you should consider Administration API instead, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html I do not like what you are trying to accomplish, however.